# Java importing library source code ExceptionInInitializerError exception

Tags: java, exception, import, owl

I imported in my project source code of a library in order to change some parts of the library.
But when I launch the program I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at impl.owls.OWLSConverters.registerConverters(OWLSConverters.java:138)

This is OWLSConverters.java:

```
class OWLSConverters
{
    static final void registerConverters(final OWLObjectConverterRegistry registry)
    {
        final OWLObjectConverter<Service> serviceConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<Service>(ServiceImpl.class, OWLS.Service.Service);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Profile> profileConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<Profile>(ProfileImpl.class, OWLS.Profile.Profile);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Actor> actorConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<Actor>(ActorImpl.class, OWLS.Actor.Actor);
        final OWLObjectConverter<ServiceParameter> serviceParamConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<ServiceParameter>(ServiceParameterImpl.class, OWLS.ServiceParameter.ServiceParameter);
        final OWLObjectConverter<ServiceCategory> serviceCategoryConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<ServiceCategory>(ServiceCategoryImpl.class, OWLS.ServiceCategory.ServiceCategory);

        final OWLObjectConverter<AtomicProcess> atomicProcessConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<AtomicProcess>(AtomicProcessImpl.class, OWLS.Process.AtomicProcess);
        final OWLObjectConverter<CompositeProcess> compositeProcessConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<CompositeProcess>(CompositeProcessImpl.class, OWLS.Process.CompositeProcess);
        final OWLObjectConverter<SimpleProcess> simpleProcessConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<SimpleProcess>(SimpleProcessImpl.class, OWLS.Process.SimpleProcess);

        final List<OWLObjectConverter<? extends Process>> prCs =
            new ArrayList<OWLObjectConverter<? extends Process>>(3);
        prCs.add(atomicProcessConverter);
        prCs.add(compositeProcessConverter);
        prCs.add(simpleProcessConverter);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Process> processConverter = new CombinedOWLConverter<Process>(Process.class, prCs);

        final OWLObjectConverter<Existential> existentialConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<Existential>(ExistentialImpl.class, OWLS.Process.Existential);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Input> inputConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<Input>(InputImpl.class, OWLS.Process.Input);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Output> outputConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<Output>(OutputImpl.class, OWLS.Process.Output);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Link> linkConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<Link>(LinkImpl.class, OWLS.Process.Link);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Loc> locConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<Loc>(LocImpl.class, OWLS.Process.Loc);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Participant> participantConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<Participant>(ParticipantImpl.class, OWLS.Process.Participant);
        final OWLObjectConverter<ResultVar> resultVarConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<ResultVar>(ResultVarImpl.class, OWLS.Process.ResultVar);


        final List<OWLObjectConverter<? extends Local>> localCs =
            new ArrayList<OWLObjectConverter<? extends Local>>(2);
        localCs.add(locConverter);
        localCs.add(linkConverter);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Local> localConverter =
            new CombinedOWLConverter<Local>(Local.class, localCs);

        final List<OWLObjectConverter<? extends Parameter>> paCs =
            new ArrayList<OWLObjectConverter<? extends Parameter>>(2);
        paCs.add(inputConverter);
        paCs.add(outputConverter);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Parameter> parameterConverter =
            new CombinedOWLConverter<Parameter>(Parameter.class, paCs);

        final List<OWLObjectConverter<? extends ProcessVar>> procVarCs =
            new ArrayList<OWLObjectConverter<? extends ProcessVar>>(5);
        procVarCs.add(parameterConverter);
        procVarCs.add(localConverter);
        procVarCs.add(resultVarConverter);
        procVarCs.add(existentialConverter);
        procVarCs.add(participantConverter);
        final OWLObjectConverter<ProcessVar> processVarConverter =
            new CombinedOWLConverter<ProcessVar>(ProcessVar.class, procVarCs);

        final OWLObjectConverter<Expression.SPARQL> sparqlExprConverter =
            InternalFactory.createExpressionConverter(Expression.SPARQL.class,
                OWLS.Expression.SPARQL_Expression, OWLS.Expression.Expression, OWLS.Expression.SPARQL);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Expression.SWRL> swrlExprConverter =
            InternalFactory.createExpressionConverter(Expression.SWRL.class,
                OWLS.Expression.SWRL_Expression, OWLS.Expression.Expression, OWLS.Expression.SWRL);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Condition.SPARQL> sparqlCondConverter =
            InternalFactory.createExpressionConverter(Condition.SPARQL.class,
                OWLS.Expression.SPARQL_Condition, OWLS.Expression.Condition, OWLS.Expression.SPARQL);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Condition.SWRL> swrlCondConverter =
            InternalFactory.createExpressionConverter(Condition.SWRL.class,
                OWLS.Expression.SWRL_Condition, OWLS.Expression.Condition, OWLS.Expression.SWRL);


        final List<OWLObjectConverter<? extends Expression>> exprCs =
            new ArrayList<OWLObjectConverter<? extends Expression>>(2);
        exprCs.add(sparqlExprConverter);
        exprCs.add(swrlExprConverter);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Expression> expressionConverter =
            new CombinedOWLConverter<Expression>(Expression.class, exprCs);

        final List<OWLObjectConverter<? extends QuotedExpression>> quotedExprCs =
            new ArrayList<OWLObjectConverter<? extends QuotedExpression>>(2);
        quotedExprCs.add(sparqlExprConverter);
        final OWLObjectConverter<QuotedExpression> quotedExpressionConverter =
            new CombinedOWLConverter<QuotedExpression>(QuotedExpression.class, quotedExprCs);

        final List<OWLObjectConverter<? extends Condition>> condCs =
            new ArrayList<OWLObjectConverter<? extends Condition>>(2);
        condCs.add(sparqlCondConverter);
        condCs.add(swrlCondConverter);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Condition> conditionConverter =
            new CombinedOWLConverter<Condition>(Condition.class, condCs);

        final GenericOWLConverter<VariableBinding> variableBindingConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<VariableBinding>(VariableBindingImpl.class, OWLS.Expression.VariableBinding);

        final OWLObjectConverter<AsProcess> asProcessConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<AsProcess>(AsProcessImpl.class, OWLS.Process.AsProcess);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Perform> performConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<Perform>(PerformImpl.class, OWLS.Process.Perform);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Sequence> sequenceConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<Sequence>(SequenceImpl.class, OWLS.Process.Sequence);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Choice> choiceConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<Choice>(ChoiceImpl.class, OWLS.Process.Choice);
        final OWLObjectConverter<AnyOrder> anyOrderConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<AnyOrder>(AnyOrderImpl.class, OWLS.Process.AnyOrder);
        final OWLObjectConverter<IfThenElse> ifThenElseConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<IfThenElse>(IfThenElseImpl.class, OWLS.Process.IfThenElse);
        final OWLObjectConverter<RepeatWhile> repeatWhileConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<RepeatWhile>(RepeatWhileImpl.class, OWLS.Process.RepeatWhile);
        final OWLObjectConverter<RepeatUntil> repeatUntilConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<RepeatUntil>(RepeatUntilImpl.class, OWLS.Process.RepeatUntil);
        final OWLObjectConverter<ForEach> forEachConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<ForEach>(ForEachImpl.class, OWLS.Process.ForEach);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Set> setConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<Set>(SetImpl.class, OWLS.Process.Set);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Split> splitConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<Split>(SplitImpl.class, OWLS.Process.Split);
        final OWLObjectConverter<SplitJoin> splitJoinConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<SplitJoin>(SplitJoinImpl.class, OWLS.Process.SplitJoin);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Produce> produceConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<Produce>(ProduceImpl.class, OWLS.Process.Produce);


        final List<OWLObjectConverter<? extends Iterate>> itCs =
            new ArrayList<OWLObjectConverter<? extends Iterate>>(3);
        itCs.add(repeatWhileConverter);
        itCs.add(repeatUntilConverter);
        itCs.add(forEachConverter);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Iterate> iterateConverter = new CombinedOWLConverter<Iterate>(Iterate.class, itCs);


        final List<OWLObjectConverter<? extends ControlConstruct>> ccCs =
            new ArrayList<OWLObjectConverter<? extends ControlConstruct>>(13);
        ccCs.add(performConverter);
        ccCs.add(sequenceConverter);
        ccCs.add(choiceConverter);
        ccCs.add(anyOrderConverter);
        ccCs.add(ifThenElseConverter);
        ccCs.add(repeatWhileConverter);
        ccCs.add(repeatUntilConverter);
        ccCs.add(forEachConverter);
        ccCs.add(setConverter);
        ccCs.add(splitConverter);
        ccCs.add(splitJoinConverter);
        ccCs.add(produceConverter);
        ccCs.add(asProcessConverter);
        final OWLObjectConverter<ControlConstruct> controlConstructConverter =
            new CombinedOWLConverter<ControlConstruct>(ControlConstruct.class, ccCs);


        final ListConverter<OWLIndividual> objListConverter = new ListConverter<OWLIndividual>(OWLS.ObjectList.List);
        final ListConverter<OWLValue> listConverter = new ListConverter<OWLValue>(RDF.ListVocabulary);

        final ListConverter<ControlConstruct> ccListConverter = new ListConverter<ControlConstruct>(OWLS.Process.CCList);
        final ListConverter<ControlConstruct> ccBagConverter = new ListConverter<ControlConstruct>(OWLS.Process.CCBag);


        final OWLObjectConverter<InputBinding> inputBindingConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<InputBinding>(InputBindingImpl.class, OWLS.Process.InputBinding);
        final OWLObjectConverter<LinkBinding> linkBindingConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<LinkBinding>(LinkBindingImpl.class, OWLS.Process.LinkBinding);
        final OWLObjectConverter<LocBinding> locBindingConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<LocBinding>(LocBindingImpl.class, OWLS.Process.LocBinding);
        final OWLObjectConverter<OutputBinding> outputBindingConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<OutputBinding>(OutputBindingImpl.class, OWLS.Process.OutputBinding);

        final List<OWLObjectConverter<? extends Binding>> biCs =
            new ArrayList<OWLObjectConverter<? extends Binding>>(4);
        biCs.add(inputBindingConverter);
        biCs.add(outputBindingConverter);
        biCs.add(locBindingConverter);
        biCs.add(linkBindingConverter);
        final OWLObjectConverter<Binding> bindingConverter = new CombinedOWLConverter<Binding>(Binding.class, biCs);


        final OWLObjectConverter<Result> resultConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<Result>(ResultImpl.class, OWLS.Process.Result);
        final OWLObjectConverter<ValueOf> valueOfConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<ValueOf>(ValueOfImpl.class, OWLS.Process.ValueOf);


        registry.registerConverter(Service.class, serviceConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Profile.class, profileConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(ServiceParameter.class, serviceParamConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(ServiceCategory.class, serviceCategoryConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Actor.class, actorConverter);


        registry.registerConverter(AtomicProcess.class, atomicProcessConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(CompositeProcess.class, compositeProcessConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(SimpleProcess.class, simpleProcessConverter);
        registry.extendByConverter(Process.class, processConverter);

        registry.registerConverter(AsProcess.class, asProcessConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Perform.class, performConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Sequence.class, sequenceConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Choice.class, choiceConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(AnyOrder.class, anyOrderConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(IfThenElse.class, ifThenElseConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Iterate.class, iterateConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(RepeatWhile.class, repeatWhileConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(RepeatUntil.class, repeatUntilConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(ForEach.class, forEachConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Set.class, setConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Split.class, splitConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(SplitJoin.class, splitJoinConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Produce.class, produceConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(ControlConstruct.class, controlConstructConverter);

        registry.registerConverter(Existential.class, existentialConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Input.class, inputConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Link.class, linkConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Loc.class, locConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Output.class, outputConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Participant.class, participantConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(ResultVar.class, resultVarConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Local.class, localConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Parameter.class, parameterConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(ProcessVar.class, processVarConverter);

        registry.registerConverter(InputBinding.class, inputBindingConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(OutputBinding.class, outputBindingConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(LinkBinding.class, linkBindingConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(LocBinding.class, locBindingConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Binding.class, bindingConverter);

        registry.registerConverter(Result.class, resultConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(ValueOf.class, valueOfConverter);

        registry.registerListConverter(OWLS.ObjectList.List, objListConverter);
        registry.registerListConverter(RDF.ListVocabulary, listConverter);
        registry.registerListConverter(OWLS.Process.CCList, ccListConverter);
        registry.registerListConverter(OWLS.Process.CCBag, ccBagConverter);

        registry.registerConverter(Expression.SPARQL.class, sparqlExprConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Expression.SWRL.class, swrlExprConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Condition.SPARQL.class, sparqlCondConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(Condition.SWRL.class, swrlCondConverter);
        registry.extendByConverter(Condition.class, conditionConverter);
        registry.extendByConverter(Expression.class, expressionConverter);
        registry.extendByConverter(QuotedExpression.class, quotedExpressionConverter);
        registry.registerConverter(VariableBinding.class, variableBindingConverter);
    } }
```

Here i have the java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError exception:

```
final OWLObjectConverter<ServiceParameter> serviceParamConverter =
            new GenericOWLConverter<ServiceParameter>(ServiceParameterImpl.class, OWLS.ServiceParameter.ServiceParameter);
```

Other information about exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fatal: Failed to load OWL
>   ontology file
>   http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.2/ServiceParameter.owl#! Details:
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to read ontology. Details:
>   com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.DoesNotExistException:
>   http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.2/ServiceParameter.owl

The problem is here:

```
public static abstract class ServiceParameter
    {
        public static final OWLClass ServiceParameter;
        public static final OWLObjectProperty serviceParameter;
        public static final OWLDataProperty serviceParameterName;
        public static final OWLObjectProperty sParameter;

        static
        {
            final OWLOntology ont = loadOntology(SERVICE_PARAMETER_NS);

            ServiceParameter = ont.getClass(URIUtils.createURI(SERVICE_PARAMETER_NS + "ServiceParameter"));
            serviceParameter = ont.getObjectProperty(URIUtils.createURI(SERVICE_PARAMETER_NS + "serviceParameter"));
            serviceParameterName = ont.getDataProperty(URIUtils.createURI(SERVICE_PARAMETER_NS + "serviceParameterName"));
            sParameter       = ont.getObjectProperty(URIUtils.createURI(SERVICE_PARAMETER_NS + "sParameter"));
        }
```

> final OWLOntology ont = loadOntology(SERVICE_PARAMETER_NS);

THIS METHOD THROW THE EXCEPTION!

```
protected static OWLOntology loadOntology(final String ontologyURL, final String local)
{
    logger.info("Loading ontology {} ...", ontologyURL);

    URI uri = URIUtils.standardURI(ontologyURL);
    OWLOntology loadedOnt;
    try
    {
        loadedOnt = kb.read(uri);
        loadedOnt.setReadOnly(true);
        return loadedOnt;
    }
    catch (final IOException ioe)
    {
        String details = ioe.toString();
        if (local != null)
        {
            InputStream in = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(local);
            try
            {
                loadedOnt = kb.read(in, uri);
                loadedOnt.setReadOnly(true);
                return loadedOnt;
            }
            catch (IOException iioe)
            {
                details += ", " + iioe.toString();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (in != null) try
                {
                    in.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ignore)
                {
                    // fall through, we can not recover anyway
                }
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "Fatal: Failed to load OWL ontology file " + ontologyURL + "! Details: " + details);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a static initializer?

Comment: Yes, this Exception is thrown from a static initializer, so the first access to class will throw this.

Comment: If i do the some thing with the .jar librart i have no problem
Why i have this exception with the source code? How can i solve?

Yes, i see there is a static initializer in the source code!!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8VKWY4Vj

Comment: Further down the stacktrace should be a message `Caused by ...`.  This will tell you the real reason you're getting an exception.  An ExceptionInInitializerError merely indicates that an exception was thrown in a static initializer.  Without seeing the rest of your code, or the rest of your stacktrace, we can't hope to tell your what your problem is.

Comment: @LukeWoodward , now i add all the information about the error!

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the missing URL with this version - it looks like it's the same file to me.

`http://www.ai.sri.com/daml/services/owl-s/1.2/ServiceParameter.owl`

From what I know of OWL-S, it has had little changes in the last few years, so either location should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your library / program tries to load a certain file from the internet (http://www.daml.org/services/owl-s/1.2/ServiceParameter.owl), but this file doesn't exist. This could possibly be a configurable URL (ifso, it should be configured to point to the correct location).

Also: there is a fallback scenario for when the file cannot be accessed, in which case it uses a local file (pointed to by the `local` String parameter of `loadOntology`). In this way, presumably, a local copy of the .owl file could be used, to ensure that the program is functional even when there is no internet connection. Unfortunately, this route is also unsuccessful: Your best bet is to make sure that your copy of the package contains the ServiceParameter.owl file, and that the location of this file is the same as it was in the original package.

Comment: i am sure this is the problem!! I try to put ServiceParameter.owl in every package, but i have no result :(